influxdb localhost:8086 Not found web console not opening
root@ABC-PF34ZK3G:~# influx Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.8.0 InfluxDB shell version: 1.6.7~rc0
i am able create table and query from table in ubuntu cmd promt But when try to open web console http://localhost:8086 its giving web page not found

With the information given here that is noting to offer any help with. Take a look at this link, edit the question and add the critical missing info. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
